# Unable to set the syntax of .txt file .tex in Emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax, latex

**How can you set the syntax of a .txt file .tex in Emacs?**

Comment: Do you mean how to get Emacs to load .txt files in TeX-mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For questions like this, you should refer to other resources like the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/).

In your `.emacs`, you could do something like:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (append '(("\\.txt$" . tex-mode))
    auto-mode-alist))
```

Also, you could change the modeline of the current buffer using:

```
M-x tex-mode
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also put the following at the start of the file:

```
% -*- TeX -*-
```

That will signal to emacs that your file should be in tex-mode.